# How to find the name of every column in a sqlite3 database

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a database (called riverdata) and in it I have one table (called riverdata). This table has many different columns with data in them. Is there some kind of query I could run on serverside javascript that would give me the individual names of each column? Thanks.

Comment: Anything tried as far?

Comment: i tried using conn.query('PRAGMA riverdata(riverdata)') because I saw that somewhere while looking before, but the query returned nothing